# Yahoo Pipes and regex: Why does it work only for my first item?

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

Here is my pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a732be6cf2b7cb92cec5f9ee6ebca756

I am currently trying to get the part before the first space to my item.url and the second part will be the title.

For instance, first item is:

```
http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 Crachet 7/12
```

The expected result would be to get the "Crachet 7/12" as title and the other part as link.

My regex query `"([^\s]+)"` seem to work only for my first item, I don't understand why, as all the items are formatted the same way.

Thank a lot for any help!

EDIT: Pictures to understand better:

**BEFORE REGEX**
[image]

**AFTER REGEX**
[image]

**Trying to check the g symbol**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\S+` instead of `[^\s]+`. Also, you need to specify the "global" flag or the regex engine stops after the first successful match. In order to match only the first non-whitespace part of the line, use the `^` anchor with the "multiline" flag:

```
/^\S+/gm
```

or

```
new RegExp("^\\S+", "gm")
```

In your case, you need to check the appropriate checkboxes.

Comment: You may have a look at the pictures in first post to understand better... I hope that will be enough

Comment: Check the "g" checkbox and try again. You might want to anchor the search to the start of the line, though, or all non-space text will be removed. See my edit.

Comment: By checking "g", everything is broken ( see third picture)