# In my string, there is a character that I cannot identify that seems to be a space (Regex)

Tags: regex, character, space, yahoo-pipes

I have a string that I need to parse using regex.
This string is:

> **http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 Crachet 7/12**

What I try to do is to separate the url and the comment, so I tried:

(\S+)\s(.+) 
but as result, I get:

$1 = > **http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 Crachet**

$2 = > **7/12**

So, it seem that first character is not a space!

I tried to replace \s by 'X' and got

> **http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 CrachetX7/12**

I am sure to have something strange.

I tried to replace every character by 'X' (\n, \t, etc.) but cannot find what is this "space lookalike"

How can I identify this character and split my string?

**EDIT:**

If you want to play with my code, this is a Yahoo! Pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=a732be6cf2b7cb92cec5f9ee6ebca756

According to the [Pipes documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex), it looks like it uses fairly standard regex syntax.

**Some tests:**

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: What language? Please tag it. Your regex works perfectly fine in perl, for example.

Comment: That's Yahoo! Pipes (added to my question)

Comment: Your pipes example ... works fine. It shows `title` as `Crachet 7/12` (?)

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7596250/20670), `\S+` matched the part up to the first space before `Crachet` correctly as evidenced by the second screenshot. So what did change in-between?

Comment: It worked only for the first one... I need a few minuts of reflexion to put all the information together.. Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: You still haven't anchored the regex to the start of the line (`^` anchor) or used the multiline modifier (`m`) --> `^(\S+)...` and check the `m` checkbox.

Comment: Ok, now \S+ is working fine! Just need the opposite of (\S+), so I can extract the other filed. Please post in answer, so I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex

```
^(\S+)\s+(.*)$
```

with the `g` and `m` modifier checkboxes checked.

Comment: g had not to be checked, gave errors when multiple words at second part. ;-)